# Member variable inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a variable in my implementation and it states that "its inaccessible due to its protection level"

```
namespace mytest
{
    public class IDatabaseSettings
    {
        string connection { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace mytest
{
    public class DatabaseSettings : IDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string connection{ get; set; }
    }
}

IDatabaseSettings settings = new DatabaseSettings();
settings.connection <--- is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Any suggestions on why this might be happening ?

Comment: Did you mean to declare `IDatabaseSettings` as an interface rather then as a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a public class, the property you created is private. The default when you don't specify an access modifier on a *class* is private. Interfaces do not allow access modifiers as everything is assumed public (otherwise the interface would not be useful).

Use this instead on your `DatabaseSettings` class (the interface is fine):

```
public string connection { get; set; }
```

Also, your interface is defined as a class. Define it as an interface instead:

```
public interface IDatabaseSettings
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry i had it as public but i am still getting this message

Comment: Ahh, your interface is defined as a class. Change `public class IDatabaseSettings` to `public interface IDatabaseSettings`

Comment: yep. You nailed it. Thank you. Marked as answer